# creating a JSON object by looping through li

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, loops

I am hoping someone can see where I am going wrong here, I am having some problems trying to create a JSON object by looping through all of my list items.

Basically, what I am trying to achieve in the long run is to get a PHP array like:

```
$positions = array(
1 => 2,
2 => 3,
3 => 4,
4 => 5,
5 => 6,
6 => 1);
```

I need to create a JSON object with all of my list items so that I can send it with AJAX later. I need it to be in this format:

```
[{1:2, 2:3, 3:4, 4:5, 5:6, 6:1}]
```

The code that I currently have is:

```
    <li data-serial="6" data-newpos="1"></li>

    jsonObj = [];
    $("li.item").each(function() {
            var id = $(this).attr('data-serial');
            jsonObj.push({
                id: $(this).attr('data-newpos')
            });
        });
        alert(JSON.stringify(jsonObj));
```

But this gives me this outcome which is not what I need:

```
[{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"},{"id":"3"},{"id":"4"},{"id":"5"},{"id":"6"}]
```

Any help at all would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't really get your question, as `[{1:2, 2:3, 3:4, 4:5, 5:6, 6:1}]` is not valid json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
jsonObj = {};
$("li.item").each(function() {       
               var id = $(this).attr('data-serial');
               jsonObj[ id ] = $(this).attr('data-newpos');
             });
```

This will give you an object of this form (assuming the `data.` properties are correct)

```
{"1":"2", "2":"3", "3":"4", "4":"5", "5":"6", "6":"1"}
```